# Add affiliations to the authors' name in the article class

Tags: article

I am using the `\documentclass{article}` to write an article. how can I add the affiliation to the author's name like the following picture?

[image]

And, this document class has a date under the names. Can I omit it?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Using `authblk` maybe it's better to do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{This is some thing}
\author[1]{Don Joe}
\author[2]{Smith K.}
\author[1]{Wanderer}
\author[1]{Static}
\affil[1]{TeX.SX}
\affil[2]{Both on a bus}
\date{}                     %% if you don't need date to appear
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

This way, you can mix affiliations.

Comment: Thanks @Harish Kumar for very helpful answer. I do a have a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303678/4821). Would highly appreciate if you have a look on this and provide any answer. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work in amsart class. Wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: Could you explain why you changed the `Maxaffil` counter? I don't really see the purpose.

Answer (score 69):

When I've needed to use `\maketitle`, a trick I've used is to abuse `\date{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My Title}
\author{Author One$^1$ \and Author Two$^2$}
\date{%
    $^1$Organization 1\\%
    $^2$Organization 2\\[2ex]%
    \today
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Quick and dirty, but quite effective (!). Thanks

Comment: This is really handy!

Comment: I normally manipulate the author field to add affiliations, but I think the date manipulation works better.  In the author field, you can't increase spacing between name and additional objects.

Comment: Hi, I am using the above but "No institute given" text is comming after the names of the authors.

Answer (score 38):

I always use a trick I learned from [Anthony Liekens](http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences), which is used for showing multiple affiliations per author.
Omitting the date is as easy as using `\date{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
} 
\title{How to bowl properly}
\author{%
  The Dude\footremember{alley}{Holly Star Lanes Bowling Alley}%
  \and Walter Sobchak\footremember{trailer}{Probably in a trailer park}%
  \and Jesus Quintana\footrecall{alley} \footnote{Mexico?}%
  \and Uli Kunkel\footrecall{trailer} \footnote{Germany?}%
  }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The whole example is taken from \href{http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences}{Anthony Liekens}\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I feel this should be the answer.