# How to place the author's affiliation in a specific place

Tags: affiliation

I am writing an article and I would like to place the affiliation of the authors right after them and before the abstract, just like in the image. I would like to maintain the footnote's style, but with the text placed before the abstract instead of at the bottom of the page. How could I do that in a article document class?[image]

Comment: You can have a look there http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214408/64454

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `authblk` package this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{authblk}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author[1]{John Doe}
\author[1,2]{Erika Musterman}
\affil[1]{Somewhere}
\affil[2]{Over the rainbow}

\date{}

\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Disclaimer:* all credits to [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar), thanks to its answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214408/64454).