# How to set style file for Urdu paper

Tags: macros, xetex, templates

I wonder, if it's not difficult for you, I am uploading a LaTeX code which returns Urdu text in `XeLaTeX`, however, can you arrange its preamble into a separate style file and LaTeX body file?
Like, the style, used in research papers.

```
%% __________ %%% ______________ %%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twosided,openright,notitlepage,numbers,sort&compress]{article}
\RequirePackage[a4wide]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssym,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,subfig,adjustbox} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,sidecap}%%showframe, creates frame on each page
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,multido,pgfplots,pagecolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,matrix,mindmap,shapes.misc,patterns,positioning,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
\RequirePackage{cite,super}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref} % removes color boxes around clickables
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = red!50, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = green %Colour of citations
}
%%%%%%%%% Urdu Specification with Polyglossia %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu} % =eastern if east no desired!
\setotherlanguages{arabic,english} %% or others
\usepackage[english,arabic,urdu]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section} ۔ }
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi} ۔ }
\parindent 0.3in
\rightfootnoterule
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5,WordSpace=5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
%======================================================================================
%   Title and Abstract Settings
%======================================================================================
\newenvironment{affiliations}{%
       \setcounter{enumi}{1}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0in}%
    \slshape\sloppy%
    \begin{list}{\upshape$^{\arabic{enumi}}$}{%
        \usecounter{enumi}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0in}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0in}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0in}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0in}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{0in}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0ex}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{0in}%
        }
    }{\end{list}\par\vspace{12pt}}
%% Redefine the abstract environment to be the first bold paragraph
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%  
    \setlength{\parindent}{0in}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{0in}%
    \bfseries%
%\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
    }{\par\vspace{0pt}%\rule{\textwidth}{1.3pt}
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\mainmatter
\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{\LARGE  بنیادئ فزکس کو بھی کچھ تبدیلیوں کے ساتھ ترتیب}  %this is title of the paper
\newline
\item\textenglish{Saeed Akhtar^{1,2}, Amala Fida^2} %% these are authors
\begin{affiliations}
 \item\textenglish{Government Postgraduate College No.1 Abbottabad 22010}
 \footnote{
 \item\textenglish{SPINTRONICS and Nanoelectronics Research Center}}
 \footnote{\textenglish{Electronic Email: akhtar73@me.com}}
\end{affiliations}
\date{\today}
%}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \atxy{-6.65in}{11.4in}{\includegraphics[scale=1.23]{ZmI9O}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
{\noindent\fcolorbox{cyan!60}{cyan!60}{\parbox{\linewidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}{{\textcolor{white}{
بِسمِ اللہ الرّ خمّنِ الرّ خیم ہکرنا چائتے  ھیں ۔ جیسے جیسے ڈیوایئس کا سایئز کم ھوتا جاتا ھے، اسی طرح فزکس بھی تبدیل ھوتی جاتی ھے۔  
\vspace{0.15in}
\noindent
\begin{center}
اردو ہے جس کا نام ، ہمیں جانتے ہیں داغ  \\
سارے جہاں میں دھوم ہماری زباں کی ہے \\
\hspace{6cm} (داغ دھلوی)
\end{center}
}}}}
\end{abstract}  

%\bfseries%    
\vspace{0.25in}
\noindent
\hspace{0in}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{انڈکس بنانا}

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھ.
\subsection{سب ارودو میں لکھو}  

آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ 

\section{مکس سیکشن}

\textenglish{English, Urdu mix. The field of semiconductors started in the mid of the last century and was geared by the invention of the transistor where.\cite{kr1,kr2,book}}
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟آوَ سیمی کنڈکٹرز کو بھی پڑھتے ھیں۔  
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟

\vspace{0.5in}
\noindent
\begin{center}
اردو ہے جس کا نام ، ہمیں جانتے ہیں داغ  \\
سارے جہاں میں دھوم ہماری زباں کی ہے \\
\hspace{6cm} (داغ دھلوی)
\end{center} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{kr1} \textenglish{Davidson III, F. M.,  Schricker,  A.D., Wiacek,  and R. J. Korgel, B. A. Adv. Mater. 16, 646-649, (2004).} 
 \bibitem{kr2}  \textenglish{Davidson III, F. M., Lee, D. C., Fanfair, D. D., and Korgel, B. A. J. Phys. Chem. C111, 2929-2932 (2007).}
 \bibitem{book}  \textenglish{Jones, R. A. L. Soft Machines: Nanotechnology and Life Ch. 3 (Oxford Univ. Press, Oxford, 2004).}
\end{thebibliography}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `babel` and `polyglossia` at the same time.

Comment: Also, don’t use `fontenc`—and other legacy 8-bit font packages—aren’t needed with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start.  It still has a few rough edges, such as the footnote marks.

Save as `urdu-lbd.sty`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% urdu.style: Basic stylesheet to set up a document primarily in Urdu.
%% Copyright © 2020 Loren B. Davis.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
%%
%% This software is hereby released under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license, q.v.:
%% https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{urdu-lbd}[2020/07/08 An Urdu stylesheet with babel and unicode-math.]

%% As of July 2020, this document requires either LuaTeX version 1.2 or
%% higher, LuaHbTeX, or XeTeX.  I recommend lualatex if it works, but on
%% older installations, you may need to use xelatex.

%% I don’t set this in a package, but I highly recommend it in any multi-
%% lingual document.  It warns you if a font does not contain a glyph you
%% request:

%\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{iftex} % Detect the TeX engine

\ifluahbtex
  % Only LuaTeX supports bidi=basic.
  \usepackage[bidi=basic,
              layout=sectioning.lists.captions,
              english]{babel}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  
  % LuaTeX requires the HarfBuzz font shaper:
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX,
                        Renderer=HarfBuzz,
                        Scale=MatchLowercase }
                        
  % Since XeTeX does not support font expansion, only load microtype in
  % LuaTeX:
  \usepackage{microtype}
\else\ifxetex
  \usepackage[bidi=default,
              layout=sectioning.lists.captions.footnotes,
              english]{babel}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX,
                        Scale=MatchLowercase }
\else
  \PackageError{urdu}{This package requires LuaTeX 1.2 or later, LuaHbTeX, or XeTeX}
\fi\fi

%% It appears that you do NOT want to map the counters \arabic or \alph?  If
%% you do, add the option maparabic and alph=.
\babelprovide[import, main]{urdu}

%% Amiri and Libertinus are both by the same creator, Khaled Hosny (based on
%% existing fonts) and match well.  I picked sans-serif and monospace Arabic
%% fonts that are free and should be available in your TeX distribution.  The
%% Libertinus font family includes an OpenType math font, which is even one
%% of the few to have a bold weight.
%%
%% If not, they are available at:
%% https://www.amirifont.org/
%% https://github.com/alerque/libertinus
%% https://www.google.com/get/noto/
%% https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/almfixed

\PackageWarningNoLine{urdu}
  {Messages from fontspec about fonts lacking a script or language are harmless.  You can ignore them}

\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[urdu]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont[urdu]{sf}{Noto Sans Arabic}
\babelfont[urdu]{tt}{ALM Fixed}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

%% Set up \texturdu, \textenglish, \begin{urdu} and \begin{english}
\babeltags{urdu=urdu}
\babeltags{english=english}
```

And the article template.  The `fcolorbox` is at present broken in XeLaTeX, but works in LuaLaTeX 1.2 or higher.  I decided against rewriting that part of the document and will post as-is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               12pt,
               twosided,
               openright,
               notitlepage,
               numbers,
               sort&compress
              ]{article}
%% You use \mainmatter, \chapter and abstract, but there is no standard
%% document class that has all three.  I’m going to rewrite as an article.
\tracinglostchars=2
% You use \usepackage[a4wide]{geometry}, but that does not appear to be defined
% in TeX Live 2020.
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{urdu-lbd} % If it’s good enough for cfr ...?
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % enable standard HTML/CSS/SVG colors
\usepackage{tikz}
% Include your TikZ libraries here.
% You include caption twice, but I think you want these options.
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % Your comment suggests you wanted to color
% links, not hide them, so I removed hidelinks.
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = Blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = Red, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = Green %Colour of citations
}

\parindent 0.3in
%% The footnote rule is now set up in the urdu package.
%\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
%\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
%======================================================================================
%   Title and Abstract Settings
%======================================================================================

%% You had this as a chapter title, but there are no chapters in an article.
\title{بنیادئ فزکس کو بھی کچھ تبدیلیوں کے ساتھ ترتیب}  %this is title of the paper

%% If co-authors share affiliations, use \footnotemark.  Or see this solution:
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214425/61644
%%
%% I removed the affiliations environment, but you can restore it if you want.
%% This set-up has the probably-undesired side-effect that the authors are
%% listed from right to left, as in the Urdu language, but their names appear
%% in the latin script.  Thus, the second author may appear to be the first
%% author.  To remove the ambiguity, I put their names on separate lines.
%%
%% I put the author names in hboxes to work around a bug in babel 3.45.

\author{
  \hbox{\textenglish{Saeed Akhtar}}%
    \footnote{\textenglish{Government Postgraduate College No.1 Abbottabad
              22010}}
    \footnote{\textenglish{Electronic Email: akhtar73@me.com}}
  \\ \hbox{\textenglish{Amala Fida}}%
    \footnote{\textenglish{SPINTRONICS and Nanoelectronics Research Center}}
}

\date{\today}

%% Only the book document class has \mainmatter, but lacks an abstract.

\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \atxy{-6.65in}{11.4in}{\includegraphics[scale=1.23]{ZmI9O}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%% I’m going to skip rewriting this, but it should probably be part of
%% \renewenvironment{abstract}.
{\noindent\fcolorbox{DarkCyan}{DarkCyan}{\parbox{\linewidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}{{\textcolor{White}{
بِسمِ اللہ الرّ خمّنِ الرّ خیم ہکرنا چائتے  ھیں ۔ جیسے جیسے ڈیوایئس کا سایئز کم ھوتا جاتا ھے، اسی طرح فزکس بھی تبدیل ھوتی جاتی ھے۔  
\vspace{0.15in}
\noindent
\begin{center}
اردو ہے جس کا نام ، ہمیں جانتے ہیں داغ  \\
سارے جہاں میں دھوم ہماری زباں کی ہے \\
\hspace{6cm} (داغ دھلوی)
\end{center}
}}}}}
\end{abstract}  
   
\vspace{0.25in}
\noindent
\hspace{0in}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{انڈکس بنانا}

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟

چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھ.
\subsection{سب ارودو میں لکھو}  

آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ 

\section{مکس سیکشن}

\textenglish{English, Urdu mix. The field of semiconductors started in the mid of the last century and was geared by the invention of the transistor where.\cite{kr1,kr2,book}}
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟آوَ سیمی کنڈکٹرز کو بھی پڑھتے ھیں۔  
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
چلو تھوڑا ساتھ نھِیں چلتئ ھو؟
آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟ آوَ پھر کوشش کر کے دیکھتے ھیں۔ اسی طرح مل جل کر کام کرنے میں ھی اچھائ نظر کیوں نہیں آتی؟

\vspace{0.5in}
\noindent
\begin{center}
اردو ہے جس کا نام ، ہمیں جانتے ہیں داغ  \\
سارے جہاں میں دھوم ہماری زباں کی ہے \\
\hspace{6cm} (داغ دھلوی)
\end{center} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{kr1} \textenglish{Davidson III, F. M.,  Schricker,  A.D., Wiacek,  and R. J. Korgel, B. A. Adv. Mater. 16, 646-649, (2004).} 
 \bibitem{kr2}  \textenglish{Davidson III, F. M., Lee, D. C., Fanfair, D. D., and Korgel, B. A. J. Phys. Chem. C111, 2929-2932 (2007).}
 \bibitem{book}  \textenglish{Jones, R. A. L. Soft Machines: Nanotechnology and Life Ch. 3 (Oxford Univ. Press, Oxford, 2004).}
\end{thebibliography}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```