# Add affiliation of author as footnote on report

Tags: footnotes, report, author, affiliation

I'm trying to add author affiliation as footnote following the following response on another question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214425/252049

Following is what I have tried. I'm getting the affiliations next to the names, and not as footnotes. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

````
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
} 
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-8em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\purple}[1]{{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}\normalfont}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[minimum width=4in,font=\bfseries] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north)  {WORK IN PROGRESS – DO NOT CITE OR CIRCULATE WITHOUT PERMISSION};
    \end{tikzpicture}%

}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother



\title{something something}
\author{
  person A\footremember{insti1}{xyz uni}
  \and person B\footrecall{insti1}{xyz uni}
  \and person C\footremember{insti2} \footnote{pqr uni}
  }

  
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle```
````

Comment: Please extend your example to a proper MWE others can copy and test as is.

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that