# Formatting title, authors and affiliations plus removing date from title

Tags: titles, author, affiliation

Can someone please help me make such title format like in picture below (for a conference abstract)? It is my first time using LaTeX. I don't know how to customize title and authors/affiliations through `\maketitle`, and authors with `\maketitle` are not centered and do not fit in page. So I am looking for alternative how to style each of these elements:

1. Title
2. Authors
3. Affiliations

Spacing between authors and affiliations is one line and spacing between affiliations and text is two lines

Thanks in advance to everybody!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Would one of the replies in this link help?   

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214404/add-affiliations-to-the-authors-name-in-the-article-class

Comment: Show us what you have tried. This is not a "do it for me site", but we can try to help improve your code.

Comment: In the end I used just manual formatting tools, like so: `\begin{center}
    \textbf{{\Large TITLE}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    Author$^1$, Author$^1$, Author$^1$, Author$^1$, Author$^2$, Author$^3$, Author$^4$, Author$^5$ 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \textit{\small $^1$Affiliation}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textit{\small $^2$Affiliation}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textit{\small $^3$Affiliation}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textit{\small $^4$Affiliation}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textit{\small $^5$Affiliation}
\end{center}`